# How to use full width of viewport for text editing in VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code (1.20.1) on macOS (10.12), writing markdown text files, about the right fifth of the window is blank. I have the following possibly relevant settings:

```
"editor.wordWrap": "on",
"editor.minimap.enabled": false,
"html.format.wrapLineLength": 0,
```

This should give 'viewport wrapping', according to the default settings file.
How can I make it use the full width of the viewport? Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: can you share a screenshot?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the wrapping position is calculated based on some monospaced font and not the font used in the editor.

Using proportional font (SourceHanSans)
[image: Using proportional font]

Using monospaced font (SourceHanCodeJP)
[image: Using monospaced font]